# Cannot connecto Azure Database for PostgreSQL server when Istio injection enabled

Tags: postgresql, azure, istio

I have an AKS cluster and installed Istio 1.5.0 with all namespace auto-injection enabled, and found that my pod cannot connect to the Azure Database PostgreSQL server with its domain like "xxx.postgres.database.azure.com", I tried adding a ServiceEntry for the domain but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions at this doc: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/

Comment: Hi Rinor, thank you for your reply, I tried that and works, but it requires the field "addresses" defined in the ServiceEntry, and the addresses must be CIDR since the protocol of Postgresql is TCP. In my scenario, my service is a SaaS provided to 3p customer, it needs customers to provide the database connection string, so the CIDR is dynamic, I'm wondering why the default passthrough not works for me

Comment: One thing I think should be pointed out is that there is a PostgreSQL inside my service mesh used by my service as a meta DB.not sure if it's a bug in the iptables rules, since the port of my meta DB ant the Azure PostgresSql are both 5432

Comment: This is from the docs "If the range of the possible IPs is not known, service entries for TCP cannot be used and the external services must be called directly, bypassing the sidecar proxies." And the link for external services must be called directly is: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#direct-access-to-external-services

This seems to not be possible, when TCP needs to be used, but let's see if someone has better knowledge ✌️